# Having trouble passing a variable to a flow on reRender after clicking submit button

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to pass a variable from   in through a Flow. I am new to VisualForce pages so please excuse my ignorance.

I have attached the code below for the controller and VisualForce page.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="textInput" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!actionMethod}" reRender="myFlow" value="GO"/>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:variable var="input" value="Hello1" />
    <flow:interview name="testFlow" id="myFlow">
        <apex:param name="inputFromVF" value="{!inputValue}" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!inputValue}" />
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public class testController{

public Flow.Interview.testFlow myFlow {get; set;}
public testController() {

public PageReference actionMethod() {
    return null;
}


public String inputValue { get; set; }

}
```

When I click the button to refresh the variables the output text refreshes but it doesn't accept the variable value in the parameter. I can hard code something in and it passes it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a solution after sleeping on it for the night. I set the flow as unrendered when the VF page is first ran and then I render it with the new variable and it works. It is always the easy answers.

The code is below.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="textInput" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!actionMethod}" value="GO" reRender="flowPanel, myFlow">
    </apex:commandButton>
</apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="flowPanel" rendered="true">

<apex:variable var="input" value="{!inputValue}" />
<apex:outputText value="{!inputValue}" />
    <flow:interview name="testFlow" id="myFlow" rendered="{!renderOrNot}">
        <apex:param name="inputFromVF" value="{!inputCti}" id="parameter" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!inputCti}" />
    </flow:interview>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex Controller

```
public class testController{

public String inputValue { get; set; }
public Boolean renderPanel { get; set; }
public String inputCti { get; set; }
public Boolean renderOrNot { get; set; }

public Flow.Interview.testFlow testFlow {get; set;}

public String actionMethod() {
    renderOrNot = true;
    inputCti = inputValue;
    return null;        
}
```

}